# Python re.match takes much longer time to match this

Tags: python, regex

I have a requirement to find the input strings matching patterns like below:

```
'fe{10,20}.clustera1.example.com'
'fe{10,20}.clustera{1,2}.example.com,fe{1,5}.clusterb{1,8}.example.com'
```

Hostnames or `{}` blocks in the hostnames can be repeated any number of times in an input string.

I first tried to match using the re module and is taking 10-30 seconds in some certain situations. For example, if a space is added to the end of the input string like below:

```
'fe{10,20}.clustera{1,2}.example.com,fe{1,5}.clusterb{1,8}.example.com '
```

This is taking too long to finish.

```
import re
string = 'fe{10,20}.clustera{1,2}.example.com,fe{1,5}.clusterb{1,8}.example.com '
print re.match('^([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+(,([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+)*$', string).group(0)
```

Even a simplified version (not checking the correct placement of `,` inside `{}` blocks) behaves the same way.

```
print re.match('^([a-z.-]+|{[\d,]+})+(,([a-z.-]+|{[\d,]+})+)*$', string).group(0)
```

Tried the same regex in Perl and using Python regex module. Both works fine and fast.

Here, both matches nothing (expected) but works very fast.

```
echo 'fe{10,20}.clustera{1,2}.example.com,fe{1,5}.clusterb{1,8}.example.com ' | \
perl -nle 'print $_ if /^([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+(,([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+)*$/'

import regex
string = 'fe{10,20}.clustera{1,2}.example.com,fe{1,5}.clusterb{1,8}.example.com '
print re.match('^([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+(,([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+)*$', string).group(0)
```

Is there something really wrong with the regex pattern I used? Is it possible to make it working using re module itself?

Python versions used to test are 2.7.6 and 2.7.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some definite performance bugs in re.  This particular one is aggravated by having the '$' at the end of your pattern.  If you remove this, then the match will complete quickly, and you can then manually determine if it reaches all the way to the end of the line/string.

If you have time, you might want to get the latest beta version of Python, and make sure the bug exists and then report it.  [I reported one](https://bugs.python.org/issue24426) not too long ago, and they made it better.

Answer (score 3):

Your input string example has a trailing space, but your regular expression does not allow for a trailing space.  So, either of these:

```
>>> text = 'fe{10,20}.clustera{1,2}.example.com,fe{1,5}.clusterb{1,8}.example.com'
>>> re.match('^([a-z.-]+|{[\d,]+})+(,([a-z.-]+|{[\d,]+})+)*$', text)
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 69), match='fe{10,20}.clustera{1,2}.example.com,fe{1,5}.clust>
>>> text = 'fe{10,20}.clustera{1,2}.example.com,fe{1,5}.clusterb{1,8}.example.com '
>>> re.match('^([a-z.-]+|{[\d,]+})+(,([a-z.-]+|{[\d,]+})+)*\s*$', text)
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 70), match='fe{10,20}.clustera{1,2}.example.com,fe{1,5}.clust>
```

match quickly.  On your original input, I'm not sure it can find a match -- it will exhaustively search according to the rules until all possibilities are exhausted, and then will have no match.

What are the rules, specifically, of a given regular expression?  You can look at them if you compile a regular expression with the `re.DEBUG` flag:

```
>>> re.compile('^([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+(,([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+)*$', re.DEBUG)
at at_beginning
max_repeat 1 4294967295
  subpattern 1
    branch
      max_repeat 1 4294967295
        in
          range (97, 122)
          literal 46
          literal 45
    or
      literal 123
      max_repeat 1 4294967295
        in
          category category_digit
      max_repeat 0 4294967295
        subpattern 2
          literal 44
          max_repeat 1 4294967295
            in
              category category_digit
      literal 125
max_repeat 0 4294967295
  subpattern 3
    literal 44
    max_repeat 1 4294967295
      subpattern 4
        branch
          max_repeat 1 4294967295
            in
              range (97, 122)
              literal 46
              literal 45
        or
          literal 123
          max_repeat 1 4294967295
            in
              category category_digit
          max_repeat 0 4294967295
            subpattern 5
              literal 44
              max_repeat 1 4294967295
                in
                  category category_digit
          literal 125
at at_end
    re.compile(r'^([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+(,([a-z.-]+|{[\d]+(,[\d]+)*})+)*$',
re.UNICODE|re.DEBUG)
```

Where it says `literal <num>`, you can find what this translates to in an ascii or unicode point table, like the one found at [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com).

If you can see that there are two huge loops here, the first `max_repeat` and the second `max_repeat`, each containing many sub loop/searches. The regex engine is searching over permutations of this to try and find a match.  If you can reason a little bit about the operational rules returned by `re.DEBUG`, it can help you understand what the regular expression engine might be doing.

Comment: All good information, but I think the performance hit he is seeing is completely non-linear.  There are several edge cases like that in re, which is why they are working on a replacement module.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation why it is taking too long. But I am still wondering why it should run such huge loops and run into trouble.

Comment: @meharo - the "loops" give it a space of possibilities to search through to find a match. In the case of your regex/input text, I don't think that there is a match (I've been letting that regex and that input text run for over 45 minutes, and it still hasn't realized that there is no match). The regex engine doesn't know that there isn't a match, for sure, until it tries all of the possibilities your pattern allows and cannot somehow prune as impossible given the input.